# Seeking an elegant proof that these two infinite series are equal

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, reference-request

Recently I encountered this equality in my work:

\begin{align*}
    &\bigg( 1+\frac{1}{p-1} \bigg)
    \bigg( 1+\frac{1}{p^2-1} \bigg)
    \bigg( 1+\frac{1}{p^3-1} \bigg)
    \cdots\\
    =\quad&
    1+\frac{1}{p-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p^2-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p^2-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p^3-1}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p^3-1}\bigg(1+\cdots\bigg)
\end{align*}

If $p$ is a real number $\geq 2$, it can be easily checked by showing that the ratio of L.H.S and R.H.S tends to $1$. However, this is not the type of proof I wished for.

I'm seeking for a more elegant proof, that would also work for the case in which $p$ is a complex number. For example, is there any way to find the analytical continuation of it? Also, is there any reference for this equality? I believe there are more of this kind in the literature.

Answer (score 6):

This holds for $p\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|p|>1$. After opening the "additive" parentheses on the RHS: $$1+a_1(1+a_1(1+a_2(1+a_2(1+\ldots))))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k^2,$$ if we put $p=1/q$ (thus $|q|<1$) and use the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), this is rewritten as $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(q;q)_\infty}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-q^n}{(q;q)_n^2}q^{n(n-1)}},\qquad(a;q)_n:=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k).$$ So this is an instance of [$q$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#q-series), known to [Heine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Heine) (maybe earlier, as far as back to Euler).

---

Then, the following lines of reasoning look most natural (if not elegant) to me. (I see it in many texts on $q$-stuff; the results below are taken from *The Theory of Partitions* by G. E. Andrews).

> (Cauchy) For $|q|,|z|<1$ we have $\displaystyle\frac{(az;q)_\infty}{(z;q)_\infty}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}z^n$.

To show this, let $f(z)=(az;q)_\infty/(z;q)_\infty$; then $(1-z)f(z)=(1-az)f(qz)$, and $f(z)$ is analytic on $|z|<1$. If we put $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ here, we get $f_n-f_{n-1}=q^n f_n-aq^{n-1}f_{n-1}$. Together with the obvious $f_0=1$, this gives $f_n=(a;q)_n/(q;q)_n$ as to be shown.

In the sequel, let's omit the "$;q$" and write simply $(a)_n:=(a;q)_n$.

> (Heine) For $|q|,|z|,|b|<1$ we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(q)_n(c)_n}z^n=\frac{(b)_\infty(az)_\infty}{(c)_\infty(z)_\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(c/b)_n(z)_n}{(q)_n(az)_n}b^n$.

This is shown using $(a)_n=(a)_\infty/(aq^n)_\infty$ and the above result by Cauchy: $$\text{LHS}=\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n(cq^n)_\infty}{(q)_n(bq^n)_\infty}z^n=\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n}{(q)_n}z^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(c/b)_m}{(q)_m}(bq^n)^m\\=\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(c/b)_m}{(q)_m}b^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n}{(q)_n}(zq^m)^n=\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(c/b)_m(azq^m)_\infty}{(q)_m(zq^m)_\infty}b^m=\text{RHS}.$$

> (Heine) For $|q|<1$ and $|c|<|ab|$ we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(q)_n(c)_n}\left(\frac{c}{ab}\right)^n=\frac{(c/a)_\infty(c/b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty(c/(ab))_\infty}$.

Here the idea is to put $z=c/(ab)$ above (and extend analytically to cover the premises).

---

If we replace $(a,b,c)$ by $(1/a,1/b,z)$ in the last result, and take $a,b\to 0$, we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{(q)_n(z)_n}=\frac{1}{(z)_\infty}$$ (also known to Cauchy). Multiply by $1-z$ and take $z\to 1$ to get (out of) the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$.

Comment: Nice and instructive answer. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a small supplement to the instructive answer from @metamorphy. I couldn't see his argument in the last line at a glance and needed some intermediate steps to fully appreciate his solution. Maybe some others are interested too.

We obtain from the right-hand side of (1)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{(q)_n(z)_n}=\frac{1}{(z)_\infty}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
by multiplying by $1-z$ and taking the limit $z\to 1$:

> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{z\to 1}\frac{1-z}{(z)_\infty}
> &=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{1-z}{\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-zq^n\right)}\\
> &=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-zq^n\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^n\right)}=\frac{1}{\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-q^{n+1}\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(q)_{\infty}}}
> \end{align*}

and the left-hand side gives

> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{z\to 1}&(1-z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{(q)_n(z)_n}\\
> &=\lim_{z\to 1}(1-z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty
> \frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-zq^k\right)}\\
> &=\lim_{z\to 1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
> \frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-zq^k\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
> \frac{q^{n(n-1)}z^n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-q^k\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
> \frac{q^{n(n-1)}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty
> \frac{\left(1-q^n\right)q^{n(n-1)}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-q^{k+1}\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(1-q^n\right)q^{n(n-1)}}{(q)_{n}^2}}
> \end{align*}

showing the validity of OP's identity for $q:=\frac{1}{p}$ with $|q|<1$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(q)_{\infty}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(1-q^n\right)q^{n(n-1)}}{(q)_{n}^2}}
\end{align*}