# Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(cq^n)_{\infty}}{(bq^n)_{\infty}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(c/b)_mb^mq^{nm}}{(q)_m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, pochhammer-symbol

Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(cq^n)_{\infty}}{(bq^n)_{\infty}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(c/b)_mb^mq^{nm}}{(q)_m}$

This was taken from the following equation:
$$\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_nt^n}{(q)_n} \cdot \frac{(cq^n)\infty}{(bq^n)\infty}=\frac{(b)_\infty}{(c)_\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_nt^n}{(q)_n} \cdot \frac{(c/b)_mb^mq^{nm}}{(q)_m}$$

I have checked a closed resembling question for an answer, and I understand the first part based on the pochammer identity from reducing an infinite product to finite. However, like the question of this post, how does this relate to a new index $m$?[Seeking an elegant proof that these two infinite series are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097767/seeking-an-elegant-proof-that-these-two-infinite-series-are-equal?noredirect=1)

Comment: A good proof is given in this paper [Elementary derivations of summation and transformation formulas for q-series](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~george/preprints/ElDerivations/elderivations11-20-95.pdf)